# Placing the fetched username in nav header in Navigation drawer activity

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

***What I have achieved-*** Fetching username from Facebook and displaying in different activity(working good).
 
***What I'm working on and couldn't get it to work-*** I'm working on Navigation drawer activity exactly like the below one and this activity(more or less) is provided by android studio itself [image]

I hope you can notice there is a username of this random guy in this above pic,this guy has hard-coded his name in text-view which I don't want to do, instead I want to fetch it from Facebook after login.I can successfully do the second part(fetching the name from Facebook) I just don't no how to assign let me know if there is any possible way to do it.the below is the nav_header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/manner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="ma"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" /></LinearLayout>
```

**manner** is the id where I wanted to display the fetched userName and this is the .java file

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing2);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ////////Code is used to fetch the user name////////////
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        ////////Code is used to display the user name after fetchig it from other activity////////////
        TextView facebookName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.manner);

        facebookName.setText(b.getCharSequence("name"));
        /////////////////////////




        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.testing2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

There is no error in this code because the code perfectly works for different activity with the below text view

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/manner"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In oncreate of the activity try this

```
     NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
TextView txtProfileName = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.manner);
txtProfileName.setText(userName);
```

Comment: I found the solution but I couldn't have done it without your help thankyou so much dude,thankyou so much what I did was I replaced the last line with ' txtProfileName.setText(b.getCharSequence("name")); '

Comment: navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
what this part does??